# Doctrine: Mapping working on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm working on building a Zend Framework 2 website using Doctrine2. I was developing on Windows and everything works but I have uploaded my code to a Linux environment and this error has appeared:

```
 The target-entity LeuerOneYear\Entity\UserLeagueRole cannot be found in 'User\Entity\User#leagueRoles'.
```

These are my entities:

```
<?php

namespace User\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use LeuerOneYear\Entity\UserLeagueRole;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="UserId", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Login", type="string", length=15, nullable=false)
     */
    private $login;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Email", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="CreatedOn", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $createdon;

    /**
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $appRole;

    /**
     * 
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="LeuerOneYear\Entity\UserLeagueRole", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $leagueRoles;
```

and:

```
<?php

namespace LeuerOneYear\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use User\Entity\User;

/**
 * Userleaguerole
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="userleaguerole", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="UserRole_League_idx", columns={"LeagueId"}), @ORM\Index(name="UserRole_Role_idx", columns={"RoleId"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_5D9987ED631A48FA", columns={"UserId"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UserLeagueRole
{
//     /**
//      * @var \User\Entity\User
//      *
//      * @ORM\Id
//      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
//      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User\Entity\User", mappedBy="leaguerole")
//      * })
//      */
    /**
     * 
     * @var User\Entity\User $user
     * 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User\Entity\User", inversedBy="leagueRoles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="UserId", referencedColumnName="UserId")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var \LeuerOneYear\Entity\League
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="LeuerOneYear\Entity\League", inversedBy="userRoles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="LeagueId", referencedColumnName="LeagueId")
     * 
     */
    private $league;

    /**
     * @var \LeuerOneYear\Entity\LeagueRole
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="LeuerOneYear\Entity\LeagueRole")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="RoleId", referencedColumnName="RoleId")
     * })
     */
    private $role;
```

As you can see there ir ManyToOne relation between User and UserLeagueRole.

Do you know why this mapping is working on Windows but is failing in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really silly error:

This was my directory structure:

RootFolder/module/LeuerOneYear/src/leuerOneYear

Then in my module.config.php I configure my doctrine driver in this way:

```
'driver' => array(
                        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
                                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                                'cache' => 'array',
                                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
                        ),
                        'orm_default' => array(
                                'drivers' => array(
                                        __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                                )
                        ),
                ),
```

`__NAMESPACE__` is 'LeuerOneYear', not 'leuerOneYear', so as Linux is case ensitive, the mapping failed.

I have just renamed module/src/leuerOneyear to module/src/LeuerOneYear